# I want to update atime on large binary files

Tags: binary, solaris

On a list of large binary files, I want to update the atime to current time, but not affect the ctime nor mtime. (This will be an ongoing daily process).

```
touch -a foo
```

updates the atime, but it also updates the ctime which I do not want.

```
head -1 foo > /dev/null
```

works, but since the file is not divided by "lines", it takes a relatively long time.

The following accomplishes my goal, and works quickly even on a 400 MB file, but I am not sure if it is the best way to approach this.  Any feedback is welcomed.

```
od foo | head -1 >/dev/null
```

Thanks,
JimR

Comment: if you've on gnu `head`, `head -c 1` would read only the FIRST byte of the file... that should be pretty much instantaneous

Comment: Try `dd bs=1 count=1 < foo > /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

Besides [`dd`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5166/dd-1m.html#scrolltoc) mentioned in a comment, [`od`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5165/head-1.html#scrolltoc) can read a single byte:

```
od -c -N 1 foo >/dev/null
```

Eliminating the extra `head` makes it a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
touch -at <time> <file>
```

should work (works on my ext4 drive) - not sure why you would have the ctime change along with it.

Comment: POSIX doesn't specify if `ctime` should be modified or not after running the `touch -a` command so an implementation is free to do it or not. Solaris 10 distinguish reading the file (update `atime` only) and touching the file `atime` which updates the `mtime` too. This is no more the case under Solaris 11 where only `atime` is affected in both cases.